# how to get number of days with google apps script when start and end are known

Tags: date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google apps script, I'm trying to calculate the number of days between two user defined dates (start and end inclusive). I've tried a number of iterations of code I've googled but all either complete running wothout a result or return `NaN`.

to get the big picture, I have a sheet that needs to calculate a number of values for each calendar day between two user defined dates. I thought I'd first calculate the number of days between the dates, then create the list of dates with another function, then insert the calculated value with a thrid function.

this is where I conceded to needing help:

```
function daysInRange() {
  var a = new Date(shtCalc.getRange(2, 3)); // dd/mm/yyyy, 01/02/2019
  var b = new Date(shtCalc.getRange(2, 6)); // dd/mm/yyyy, 28/02/2019
  var days = Math.floor((a-b)/(24*3600*1000));
  Logger.log(days);
}
```

I've also tried:

- adding `.valueOf()` and `.getTime()` to the end of the shtCalc ranges
- not wrapping the range in `new Date()`

I was expecting `Logger.log(days);` to return `28` but instead I get `NaN`.
please help.

Comment: Hi, @mitch-NZ! You missed a small portion of conversion to `Date` - after retrieving `Range` with `getRange()` you have to extract values with either `getValue()` [top left cell] or `getValues()` [2D `Array` of values]

Comment: @OlegValter - so simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: NP! I posted it as answer explaining the issue at hand in detail (its very easy to miss something like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

If you break down what's going on, you'll see that `a-b` in your case tries to perform a mathematical operation on two instances of `Range` class, thus returns `NaN`. Then `NaN` is divided by `24*60*60*1000`, which is also `NaN` and, finally, `Math.floor()` called on `NaN` also returns `NaN` :)

**Solution**

You need to explicitly extract values from the `Range` to be able to operate on them. `SpreadsheetApp` class has two convenient methods for doing so: `getValue()`, that will extract value of the *top left cell* of the `Range`, and `getValues()`, which will extract all values in a two-dimensional `Array` structured like this:

`[ //pseudo-code;
   row1: [ col1, colN ],
   rowN: [ col1, colN ]
 ]`

**Sample**

With a small modification your code should look like this:

```
function daysInRange() {
  var a = new Date( shtCalc.getRange(2, 3).getValue() );
  var b = new Date( shtCalc.getRange(2, 6).getValue() );
  var days = Math.floor((a-b)/(24*3600*1000));
  Logger.log(days);
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `getValue()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue);
2. `getValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);